# I don't understand the new and create associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## What I want to achieve

I have created an association between movies and schedules, but I don't know how to instantiate the association, even after reading the Rails Guide.

## Code

db/schema

```rb
# movies
  create_table "movies", charset: "utf8mb4", collation: "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "year"
    t.string "description"
    t.string "image_url"
    t.integer "is_showing"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

#schedules
  create_table "schedules", charset: "utf8mb4", collation: "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "movie_id", null: false
    t.time "start_time", null: false
    t.time "end_time", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["movie_id"], name: "index_schedules_on_movie_id"
  end
```

model

movie.rb

```rb
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :schedules
end
```

schedule.rb

```
class Schedule < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :movie
end
```

controller

schedules

```rb
class SchedulesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @movies = Movie.joins(:schedules).select("movies.*", "schedules.*")
  end

###############################################################################

# I don't get it.
  def new
    @schedule = @movie.build_schedules()
  end


  def create
    @schedule = Schedule.new(schedule_params) 
    @schedule.save
    redirect_to schedules_path
  end
###############################################################################



  private
    def schedule_params
      params.require(:schedule).permit(:start_time, :end_time)
    end  
end
```

new.html.erb

```rb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <%= render 'shared/head' %>
    <title>schedule/new</title>
  </head>
    <body>
      <%= form_with model: @schedule, url: movie_schedules_path do |form| %>
        <div class="field">
          <%= form.label :start_time %>
          <%= form.date_field :start_time %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <%= form.label :end_time %>  
          <%= form.date_field :end_time %>
          <%= form.submit %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </body>
</html>
```

## What I've tried.

・Check the Rails Guide.
I was using `build` instead of `new`, but it took an argument. I didn't know what I needed for the argument part here.

```rb
# Rails Guide
@book.author = @author
@author = @book.build_author(author_number: 123,
                                  author_name: "John Doe")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do `@movie.schedules.build` to instantiate a new record for the `@movie.schedules` association because it's a has_many.

You can also do `@movie.schedules.create(schedule_params)` to create the Schedule associated to the Movie instance in one step.

`record.build_xxx` only works for has_many/belongs_to associations (you could do `some_schedule.build_movie` for example).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the Rails Guide has an argument for ``build``. Do I need any arguments?

Comment: the argument are the initial attributes values for the new object, if you pass parameters the object will have those values for each attribute, if you pass no parameters, the object will have the attributes with the generic un-assigned value (usually just `nil` for everything)

Comment: I understood that the argument is not needed since it is usually ``nil``. Is the value automatically added to @movie in ``@movie.schedules.build``? Normally, the ``@movie`` instance would need to be set to a value by itself.

Comment: Also, writing it like this will raise ``NoMethodError``.
``def new
    @schedule = @movie.schedules.build
   end
``

Comment: When you do `@schedule = @movie.schedules.build`, the initialized Schedule object will have `movie_id = @movie.id` added by ActiveRecord.

For the no method error, I guess you are not setting the `@movie` variable, I assumed it was already a variable with something on it because you have code with that.

I think you are asking a different question now though, I'd suggest you check the docs here https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-build and maybe add a new question with this specific issue instead